# Create Blob storage UNC path in cloud

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-files, file-storage

I have used blob storage as a file storage account in .NET Core Web application hosted on Azure app service(PaaS).

My requirement is to create .zip files and then attach to email where it requires UNC path for attachment.

Here I have one option to use app service local storage for temporary file creation and use in attachment.

I am searching other option to map blob storage to any virtual drive in cloud and get its UNC path or any other option?

Also, Can you please suggest what are the possible options to map Azure Blob storage drive in network? I know the following one - App service local storage, VM, Local machine network drive.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to know the concept of UNC path, and then azure webapp can be regarded as a virtual machine in essence, and azure blob storage can also be regarded as a machine. Therefore, it is not feasible to send mail directly through azure blob.

**Suggestion:**

<del>1. I check the information, you can try azure files to store files and use them.</del>

2. I think this should be the fastest way, without using other azure products.

   Download the file to the project directory, you can create a temporary folder, such as: `MailTempFolder`, you can download the file from the blob to this folder, and then you can get the UNC path to send mail.

   After the sending is successful, just delete the file, it will not occupy too much space of the azure webapp, even if the sending fails, you can still get the zip file without downloading it again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have some doubts.
Suggestion 1: I think Azure file storage is used only for containers and not for app service. I am not sure I'll check again. 
Suggestion 2: I have already mentioned that approach in my question for using temp folder of app service local storage but here my concern is to find out alternative of the same.

Comment: @SaurabhSoni It may be that I did not read the document clearly. Although the unc path can be obtained by using azure files, it is still sent by the iis of the azure web app when sending an email, so use suggestion 2 to operate it.

Comment: I have already used suggestion 2 at the moment. I am looking for some better replacement of the same if any.